# Health and Safety?

Tags: discussion

Recently, a couple of posts have caused concern about the risks involved with the advice given.

[This answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5768/should-i-print-in-a-well-ventilated-area/5769#5769), to the question [Should I print in a well ventilated area?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5768/should-i-print-in-a-well-ventilated-area/) was recently flagged along with the comment:

> The answer seem to suggest that exposure to dangerous fumes may not be dangerous after all. Do we have a policy for erroneous health advice? Do we tolerate it relying on users using common sense when reading advice on the internet? Do we remove it?

Similarly, there was [another answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5869/danger-in-3d-printing-over-a-lithium-ion-battery/6009#6009) to another question, [Danger in 3D printing over a lithium ion battery](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5869/danger-in-3d-printing-over-a-lithium-ion-battery/), that raised some eyebrows over its possible dangerous outcome.

So, I am just throwing this out there:

#### Should we have, or do we have (and if so, what is it) a policy for [potentially] dangerous advice?

Comment: Seems like a better question for the Stack team. There is nothing stated in their Terms of Service that I can see that covers this. I'm not sure what the reprimands would be if proven that an answer lead to someones death or injury. Maybe ask [law](https://law.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @tbm0115 Isn't there a (hidden) disclaimer or something for all the advice given here?

Comment: @tbm0115 - OK, thanks, I'll post something on SE.Meta later.